# How to expand argument #1?

Tags: macros, biblatex, xstring

The argument `#1` is nicely expanded if I use it like this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}
                   {#1}
```

However, if I use it like this:

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}
                   {\StrBetween[1,2]{#1}{:}{:}}
```

Then the `\StrBetween` macro is applied to the literal string `#1` instead of what `#1` is "pointing to". I am wondering:

1. Why is this so?
2. How can I "dereference" `#1`?

EDIT:

Here is a minimal working example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
file = {:name between colons:}
}
\end{filecontents}

% This works fine 
%\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{#1}
% This just outputs an empty string
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\StrBetween[1,2]{#1}{:}{:}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \printfield{file}
}

\bibliography{jobname}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full MWE so that we have code do play around with and something to start from?

Comment: Raised issue at the Git repository: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/586

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out `#1` *does* work (thanks to @egreg for following up on this), you just can't have a line break in the declaration

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{file}{\StrBetween[1,2]{\thefield{file}}{:}{:}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \printfield{file}%
}
```

Comment: I see no difference whatsoever between using `\thefield{file}` and `#1`.

Comment: @egreg Mhhh, neither do I now you mention it. I should have tested that first. The problem only occurs if we introduce a new line like in the OP. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Yes: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

There should be ***no*** space between the arguments of `\DeclareFieldFormat`. The fact that

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}
                   {#1}
```

seems to work is just incidental. If you try

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}
                   {XX#1XX}
```

you get

```
Runaway argument?
{:name between colons:}\blx@endunit \addspace \blx@execute \blx@initunit \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \blx@theformat.
```

With correct input I see no difference between using `#1` and `\thefield{file}`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
file = {:name between colons:}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \printfield{file}\addspace
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{%
  (\StrBetween[1,2]{\thefield{file}}{:}{:})%
}

\printbibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{%
  [\StrBetween[1,2]{#1}{:}{:}]%
}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I added parentheses in the first case and brackets in the second case in order to show the field format has changed.

[image]